# How to restrict the "find" command to a physical drive?

Tags: find

Often I go looking for something and resort to running `find / -name ...` 
 But when there are multiple network drives mounted it can take forever.

There doesn't appear to be any parameter to restrict it to a physical disc/volume.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can instruct `find` to never cross a filesystem boundary. From [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html):

```
-xdev  Don't descend directories on other filesystems.
```

However, this does not distinguish between filesystems on the network and on local physical drives.

Note that this means:

- `find / -xdev ...` will not, for example, go into `/proc`
- but `find /* -xdev` will.

This is because the "other filesystems" check is done with respect to the paths that were given as arguments.

Comment: Great! Thanks for pointing out that `/proc` is a differencet file system. For others, run `findmnt` could print out useful filesystem and mount info.  E.g. [`findmnt` output of my kUbuntu](https://pastebin.com/2N0xZfQd)